# Using MATLAB to solve a system of 2nd order non linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, systems-of-equations

I have 2 coupled non linear 2nd order ODEs which describe a particle's trajectory in space, subject to an initial horizontal and vertical velocity, and also to gravitational and aerodynamic forces.

$x$ is the horizontal displacement.
$y$ is the vertical displacement.
$\beta$ is a negative constant.
$\gamma$ is a negative constant.

$\ddot{x} = \beta(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)\cos(\tan^{-1}(\dot{y}/\dot{x}))$

$\ddot{y} = \beta(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)\sin(\tan^{-1}(\dot{y}/\dot{x})) + \gamma$

Initial conditions are:

$\dot{x}(0) = V_0\cos(\alpha_0)$

$\dot{x}(0) = V_0\sin(\alpha_0)$

For the sake of argument, $V_0$ and $\alpha_0$ are both known constants.

What I would like to do, is use MATLAB to plot the trajectory of this particle, i.e plot $y$ against $x$.

My first attempt was to convert this to a first order ODE, which I did successfully by setting $a = \dot{x}$ and $b = \dot{y}$. I substituted these into the ODEs, and used `ode45` to solve for $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ and plot for the time $t = 0$ to $t = 5$. However, this just shows the component velocities, and not displacement, or position. I know mathematically I would just integrate and use two more initial conditions ($x(0)=y(0)=0$), but programmatically I don't know how to do this. If anyone could shed some light I'd be grateful. This way I can also see when the $y$ displacement returns to zero (when the particle hits the ground).

Comment: Maybe you didn't code things up properly. This takes practice and patience. Hard to say much else without seeing actual code. You might find [this blog post from the MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/) helpful. They lead you through a process that automates some of this. It's not how you'd want to do it one you know how, but it may be helpful in showing you where you've made a mistake.